# Do all continuous piecewise affine functions belongs to the class ($A_1$) of Muckenhoupt functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Given $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^N$ is open, we say $\omega$: $\Omega\to [0,+\infty)$ belongs to [Muckenhoupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muckenhoupt_weights) class $A_1$ if there exists some $C>0$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{|{B}|}\int_{B(x,r)} \omega(y)\,dy\leq C\omega(x)
$$
for all balls $B\subset\Omega$.

For simplification we take $N=1$, the real line, and we take $\Omega=(0,1)$.

My question is, given $p(x)$ is a continuous piece-wise affine function and $p(x)\geq 1$, do we always have $p(x)\in A_1$? It looks to me the answer should be yes. Since $p(x)\geq 1$ and is piece-wise affine continuous, we should have $p(x)$ is bounded. Define $M=\max p(x)$, we have

$$
\frac{1}{|{B}|}\int_{B(x,r)} p(y)\,dy\leq \frac{1}{2r}\int_{x-r}^{x+r}Mdy=M\leq Cp(x)
$$
where we take $C=M$ and bring in the fact that $p(x)\geq 1$.

It should be an OK proof, but something else went wrong with this result. So I am hoping somebody can help me to verify this result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample on $(0, \infty)$ (it can be symmetrically extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$.  Let $\omega(x)$ be a function s.t. for all integers $n \geq 0$
$$\omega(x) = 1 \,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in [n, n + 1/2)$$
and 
$$\omega(x) = 1 + 2n\left(x - (n + 1/2)\right) \,\,\,\,\,\, \forall x \in [n + 1/2, n + 1)$$

Then on each segment $[n, n+1)$, the function is a constant one on the first half of the segment, and rises up (linearly) to $n + 1$ on the second half.

Now consider the set of all balls $B(n + 1/2, 1/2)$.  We have:
$$\frac{1}{|{B}|}\int_{B(x,r)} \omega(y)\,dy = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{n}{4}$$
But $\omega(n + 1/2) = 1$ for all $n$.  We cannot find a mutual constant s.t.
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{n}{4} \leq C\cdot 1$$ 
for all $n$.

Comment: I see your point. $\omega$ has to be unbounded right? I think this is the key in your counter example. You are absolutely right. However, I feel that, as I assumed in my case, if $\Omega=(0,1)$, $\omega$ is bounded and continuous, then the result should hold.

Comment: @Denoising - I'm not sure that $\Omega$ being compact is important, but it is important, at least in this example that $\omega$ is unbounded.  I don't think continuity is important.  I could have easily added in segments bringing the function back down from $n+1$ to $1$ in between each of the intervals I defined above.

Comment: I mean, by $\Omega$ being compact and $\omega$ is continuous so $\omega$ is bounded...

Comment: Aha, got it.  Sounds like a nice followup question. Although you really need $\Omega$ to be closed to invoke that statement.

Comment: I think once $\omega$ is bounded the proof is trivial, just like what I did, by choosing $C$ to be the maximal of $\omega$ and we are all set.